# Haskell's Map.findwithdefault ocaml equivalent

Tags: haskell, ocaml

Is there an equivalent of Haskell's `findWithDefault` function in OCaml?

Recall that the type of findWithDefault is
`findWithDefault :: Ord k => a -> k -> Map k a -> a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such function in the OCaml standard Map library. You can implement a version for a single map module (i.e., a single key type) something like this:

```
module M = Map.Make(String)

let find_with_default dflt map key =
    try M.find map key with Not_found -> dflt
```

Comment: You can also have a generic definition by extending the functor: `module MyMap(O:Map.OrderedType) = struct include Map.Make(O) let find_with_default dflt map key = try find map key with Not_found -> dflt end`